# Java algorithm for evenly distributing ranges of strings into buckets

Tags: java, string, algorithm

Short version - I'm looking for a Java algorithm that given a String and an integer representing a number of buckets returns which bucket to place the String into.

Long version - I need to distribute a large number of objects into bins, evenly (or approximately evenly). The number of bins/buckets will vary, so the algorithm can't assume a particular number of bins. It may be 1, 30, or 200. The key for these objects will be a String.

The String has some predictable qualities that are important. The first 2 characters of the string actually appear to be a hex representation of a byte. i.e. 00-ff , and the strings themselves are quite evenly distributed within that range. There are a couple of outliers that start differently though, so this can't be relied on 100% (though easily 99.999%). This just means that edge cases do need to be handled.

It's critical that once all the strings have been distributed that there is zero overlap in range between what values appear in any 2 bins. So, that if I know what range of values appear in a bin, I don't have to look in any other bins to find the object. So for example, if I had 2 bins, it could be that bin 0 has Strings starting with letters a-m and bin 1 starting with n-z. However, that wouldn't satisfy the need for even distribution given what we know about the Strings.

Lastly, the implementation can have no knowledge of the current state of the bins. The method signature should literally be:

public int determineBucketIndex(String key, int numBuckets);

I believe that the foreknowledge about the distribution of the Strings should be sufficient.

EDIT: Clarifying for some questions
Number of buckets *can* exceed 256. The strings do contain additional characters after the first 2, so this can be leveraged.

The buckets should hold a range of Strings to enable fast lookup later. In fact, that's why they're being binned to begin with. With only the knowledge of ranges, I should be able to look in exactly 1 bucket to see if the value is there or not. I shouldn't have to look in others.

Hashcodes won't work. I need the buckets to contain only String within a certain range of the String value (not the hash). Hashing would lose that.

EDIT 2: Apparently not communicating well.
After bins have been chosen, these values are written out to files. 1 file per bin. The system that uses these files after binning is NOT Java. It's already implemented, and it needs values in the bins that fit within a range. I repeat, hashcode will not work. I explicitly said the ranges for strings cannot overlap between two bins, using hashcode cannot work.

Comment: "if I know what range of values appear in a bin, I don't have to look in any other bins to find the object." Why does it need to be a range?

Comment: Can the number of buckets exceed 256?

Comment: You can try something like `(int)Math.floor(key.getHashCode() / (double)Integer.MAX_VALUE * numBuckets + numBuckets / 2.0)` but clearly you'll need to be *very* wary about floating point issues.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Range is important for later lookup. Any number of bins is possible. 300-400 is a very real possibility. I updated the question.

Comment: @ZongZhengLi - Hashing cannot be used. It loses the original value which is necessary for later lookup. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by hashing "loses the original value". Do you want the index to be correlated with some observable value in the string?

Comment: @ZongZhengLi Updated description again. Hashcode won't work.

Comment: Method signature suggests, the number of bins can change everytime you try to insert a word into a bin ?

Comment: Realistically it doesn't happen every time, but the method implementation shouldn't care. What really happens is there's a set of data, depending on how large it is, the number of bins is determined, files are generated. Another set of data comes in, number of bins determineds, files generated. repeat. Realistic values range from 5-10 bins up to about 300-400.

Comment: But changing ranges would mean invalidating previous bin indexes returned by the function. You simply cannot start with 10 buckets and then after a few calls reduce it to 2. That would mean invalidating previous indexes returned by the function. Ideally, this should be a constant for a given run(may be in a constructor). The function being stateless isn't helping either.

Comment: Correct. However, you're arguing a non-important point. I've already indicated that this will be used in batches. Realistically, this *must* be stateless because it's used in a massively parallel system where threads on a totally different machine can't have knowledge of state on another. Yet all of them can be launched with the same parameter so that it does work and produce a usable result.

Comment: I would suggest re-writing (and possibly resubmitting) your question.  As you can tell from people's comments / answers, your needs and constraints are quite confusing.  I still don't understand why either `String.hashcode()` or, if the implementation details of that method aren't acceptable, a similar method that ensures appropriate hashing for your object wouldn't work to select the desired bucket.  To me, everything you're describing is essentially a distributed hash map.  Providing a concrete example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I have read through your question twice and I still don't understand the constraints.  Therefore, I am making a suggestion here and you can give feedback on it.  If this won't work, please explain why.

First, do some math on the number of bins, to determine how many bits you need for a unique bin number.  Take the logarithm to base 2 of the number of bins, then take the ceiling of number of bits divided by 8.  This is the number of bytes of data you need, `numBytes`.

Take the first two letters and convert them to a byte.  Then grab `numBytes - 1` characters and convert them to bytes.  Take the ordinal value of the character (`'A'` becomes 65, and so on).  If the next characters could be Unicode, pick some rule to convert them to bytes... probably grab the least significant byte (modulus by 256).  Get `numBytes` bytes total, including the byte made from the first two letters, and convert to an integer.  Make the byte from the first two letters the least significant 8 bits of the integer, the next byte the next 8 significant bits, and so on.  Now simply take the modulus of this value by the number of bins, and you have an integer bin number.

If the string is too short and there are no more characters to turn into byte values, use `0` for each missing character.

If there are any predictable characters (for example, the third character is always a space) then don't use those characters; skip past them.

Now, if this doesn't work for you, please explain why, and then maybe we will understand the question well enough to answer it.

Comment: At first pass, this sounds viable. Going to keep digesting it, but I think you're the first person to actually grock the question itself.

Comment: @rfeak You said, you want to look at a bin and interpret something about the strings stored in that bucket. This solution is more or less hashing. Just looking at the bucket, it won't tell you what kind of strings, it stores. You can hash within a range.

Answer (score 0):

**answer edited after 2 updates to original post**

It would have been an excellent idea to include all the information in your question from the start - with your new edits, your description already gives you the answer: stick your objects into a Balanced Tree (giving you the homogenous distribution you say you need) based on the hashCode for your string's `substring(0,2)` or something similarly head-based. Then write each leaf (being a set of strings) in the BTree to file.

Comment: No, I'm not. The system that has to pick these values back out of the bins is A) not java. B) not using the algorithm that you pick. It uses the algorithm I described which requires that a "range" of String values be in a bin.

Comment: So if this is not a java question - why tag it java??

Comment: @vikingsteve - Incorrect. The implementation which places values in bins is Java. What I said was the system that picks it back out of the bins is NOT.

Comment: answer updated, please please please if you use SO in the future, include ALL that information from the get go.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt that the problem, as described, can be done perfectly.  How about this:

1. Create 257 bins.
2. Put all normal Strings into bins 0-255.
3. Put all the outliers into bin 256.

Other than the "even distribution", doesn't this meet all your requirements?

At this point, if you really want more even distribution, you could reorganize bins 0-255 into a smaller number of more evenly distributed bins.  But I think you may just have to lesses the requirements there.